# urlencode doesn't work in PHP (localhost)

Tags: php, localhost, urlencode

So i worked in a project that i need to **encode my URL**, for example in my URL i have :

```
$url = 'http://www.test.com/?sms=+212&text=bla bla'
urlencode($url);

$url = urlencode($url);
```

Also i tried `rawurlencode($url);` and i got the same **Url** without changes !!

so please if someone has any idea i will be so appreciative :)

Comment: may be a stupid question, but did you use it like `urlencode($url)` or `$url = urlencode($url);`? Only the second one would work, as the `urlencode` function returns the value, and does not change the reference.

Comment: i update my question yes i use the second one :)

Comment: how do you see that the url did not change? Are `echo`ing it?

Comment: yes i use the var_dump($url) and nothing change

Comment: You do not share anything here that would back-up your statement that it "does not work". You neither share what the expected outcome should be, what you get instead nor do you share how you test that. However: ***Rest Assured that your localhost version of PHP does not have a bug with urlencode and that it does perfectly work!*** It's more that you confuse something here. See as well you other question that deals with an URL and urlencode.

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = "http://www.test.com/?sms=+212&text=bla bla";
echo $url = urlencode($url);
```

Answer (score 1):

urlencode returns a new encoded url, doesn't change the $url passing to it. try this

```
$encoded_url = urlencode($url);
```

$encoded_url is what you want

Answer (score 0):

The second one really works:

```
$url = "http://www.test.com/?sms=+212&text=bla bla";

$url = urlencode($url);

echo $url;
```

See a <kbd>[demonstration](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NR0Uvx)</kbd>.

I also noticed that

```
$url = http://www.test.com/?sms=+212&text=bla bla
```

is an invalid string format. Use `' '` or `" "` for strings:

```
$url = "http://www.test.com/?sms=+212&text=bla bla";
```

Comment: yes this is the problem :( when i tried online it works but when i tried it in my localhost doesn't work ! i wondered it that is not working in localhost ??

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Answer (score 0):

Ur url data should be string.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.test.com/?sms=+212&text=bla bla';
$encoded = urlencode($url);
echo(urlencode($url)); //simple urlencode
echo('<br>');
echo($encoded);//output with varible
echo('<br>');
$url = urlencode($url);
echo($url);
```

Be attentive in what place u redefined ur url var. Output of that code looks like:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2F%3Fsms%3D%2B212%26text%3Dbla+bla
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2F%3Fsms%3D%2B212%26text%3Dbla+bla
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2F%3Fsms%3D%2B212%26text%3Dbla+bla
```