# simplexml_load_file, curl and file_get_contents doesn't work on the server

Tags: php, json, curl, simplexml, file-get-contents

So i have a problem that made me crazy :( when i use **simplexml_load_file, curl or file_get** in my local machine it works fine but when i moved on the server it doesn't work and i got the timeout error,

**this is my simple code :**

```
$res = simplexml_load_file(urlencode($url));
```

So please if someone has any idea i will be very appreciative :)

Comment: check with your server admin for permissions (say firewall blockings)

Comment: `urlencode($url))` is most likely doubled. normally an URL is already urlencoded. So if not the variable is misnamed ... . - oh yeah, see your other question: [urlencode doesn't work in PHP (localhost)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23491575/367456) ... you perhaps really confuse encodings here.

Answer (score 0):

Your server has probably [**allow_url_fopen**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) set to off. Edit the php.ini file, find the line

```
allow_url_fopen = Off
```

and change it to

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```